# What is the best framework to create video content management?

Tags: cms

I saw so many Content Management System (CMS) for manage contents like article, blog, news, etc.

For example: Wordpress, Joomla, etc.

But I need to create a CMS to manage video content.

### What is the best framework to create video content management?

What features must the Video Content Management System have?

- Upload video
- Automatical encode uploaded video to mp4
- Enter basic information and metadata of video
- Support live broadcast
- Support serries video

For the best, it should support environment:

- OS: Windows, MacOS, iOS, Android
- Browser: Micrsoft Edge, Safari, Mobile Safari, Google Chrome

Software license:

- Free
- Open source: MIT, GPL, etc

Comment: @Izzy: I have already add some more detail information. If there're something new, I'll add more information.

Comment: Thanks! Reopened. I've never used such a system (or even thought about) – so for me it looks fine now, but those-who-know might ask for additional details (e.g. what runs server-side where the framework must integrate). Good luck!